# TSQL Reading an XML File based on Element Attributes

Tags: xml, t-sql

I need help with extracting the data from an XML file I’ve been sent (and have no control over), normally not any issue but the way this file is structured has me confused.  Sample XML below. None of the articles I’ve searched have a solution that seems to work with this XML file in a way I need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Entities TotalResults="3">
<Entity Type="testing"><Fields>
<Field Name="type"><Value>Internal</Value></Field>
<Field Name="name"><Value>Customer123</Value></Field>
<Field Name="updated"><Value>Yes</Value></Field>
</Fields></Entity>  
<Entity Type="testing"><Fields>
<Field Name="type"><Value>External</Value></Field>
<Field Name="name"><Value>CustomerABC</Value></Field>
<Field Name="updated"><Value>Yes</Value></Field>
</Fields></Entity>
<Entity Type="testing"><Fields>
<Field Name="type"><Value>Unknown</Value></Field>
<Field Name="name"><Value>Customer456</Value></Field>
<Field Name="updated"><Value>No</Value></Field>
</Fields></Entity>
</Entities>
```

What I want is

Entity  EntityType  Name            Updated

1   Internal    Customer123  Yes

2   External    CustomerABC  Yes

3   Unknown         Customer456  No

I can get the data from the file but not in the format I need..

```
DECLARE @input XML
SELECT @input = CAST(x AS XML)FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)


 SELECT T1.steps.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(Max)') As EntityType
   FROM @input.nodes('Entities/Entity/Fields/Field') AS Tbl(Scan)
   CROSS APPLY Tbl.Scan.nodes('.') as T1(steps)       
   Where  Tbl.Scan.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'type'


   SELECT 
   T1.steps.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(Max)') As Name
   FROM @input.nodes('Entities/Entity/Fields/Field') AS Tbl(Scan)
   CROSS APPLY Tbl.Scan.nodes('.') as T1(steps)       
   Where  Tbl.Scan.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'name'

   SELECT 
   T1.steps.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(Max)') As Updated
   FROM @input.nodes('Entities/Entity/Fields/Field') AS Tbl(Scan)
   CROSS APPLY Tbl.Scan.nodes('.') as T1(steps)       
   Where  Tbl.Scan.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'updated'
```

Which gives me three separate tables with 3 rows each, is it possible to run a query which will return data as I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

incase anyone is interested.... we did following...

```
DECLARE @input XML
DECLARE @Total int
DECLARE @Count int
DECLARE @workXMl XML
DECLARE @Type varchar(max)
DECLARE @Name varchar(max)
DECLARE @Updated varchar(max)
SELECT @input = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\TEST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XMLData')   IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #XMLData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#1')   IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #1

CREATE TABLE #XMLData(
    [Type] [varchar](max) Null,
    [Name] [varchar](max) Null,
    [Updated] [varchar](max) Null)

SELECT T2.Loc.query('.') as Result into #1
FROM  @input.nodes('Entities/Entity/Fields') as T2(Loc) 

DECLARE my_cursor 
CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
Select Result from #1
OPEN my_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @workXML
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN  

SET @Updated = (SELECT @workXML.value('(Fields/Field[@Name="updated"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))
    SET @Name = (SELECT @workXML.value('(Fields/Field[@Name="name"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))
    SET @Type = (SELECT @workXML.value('(Fields/Field[@Name="type"])[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'))

    INSERT INTO #XMLData
    Values (@Type,@Name,@Updated )

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @workXML
END 
CLOSE my_cursor;
DEALLOCATE my_cursor;

Select * FROM #XMLData
```